# OnAudioFocusChangeListener does not get executed when native player is paused

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, android-music-player

I have this strange issue when if I play song with custom app player, it works fine when I receive calls OnAudioFocusChangeListener gets called which in turn deos all the appropriate things to lower the players volume. However when  have started a native android player and paused it and than started our app player it see not to do the same but just send a call notification only, no audio focus event. What could possibly cause it?

Here are the steps:

- Start android native player
- pause it
- start our app player
- call this handset
- music does not pause within our player because we don't receive OnAudioFocusChangeListener but only CallStateListener gets called.

Is it possible that OS does not send lower volume notification b/c Native OS player is paused?

Thank you